# How to handle with german Letters Ä Ö Ü by use substring function with patterns

Tags: postgresql, substring

I have problems with german letters by handle pattern values:

```
WITH  vals (id, name) AS (VALUES (0,'AÄ1234'), (1, 'EBE1234'), (2, 'AÖ1234'), (3, 'AÜ122')) 
SELECT *,  
substring("name" from '^[A-Za-z]*')
FROM vals;
```

The substring ignore the german letters Ä, Ü and Ö. I want to get AÄ, EBE, AÖ and AÜ.

What is wrong ? For replace functions works ÄÖÜ...

```
substring(replace(replace("ROUTE_NUMBER", 'Ö', 'OE'), 'Ü', 'UE') from '^[A-Za-z]*')
```

But this is not pretty...

Comment: `substring("name" from '^[A-Za-zÄÜÖäüö]*')`?

Comment: What do you intend `[A-Za-z]` to match?

Comment: i want to match the strings from the streetnames like EBE1234 - is the streetname in bavaria EBE = Ebersberg

Answer (score 1):

The umlauts are not included in the ranges `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]`. Use this pattern:

```
[A-ZÄÖÜa-zäöü]
```